# How do you model in UML Java or C# or even DB that a customer can be either a Physical Person or a Company and a Company has employees & contractors

Tags: c#, java, database-design, model, uml

All tutorials I can find always tackle with toy uml use cases like the one here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jmod0508/

I can't see how you can model this in UML Use Case:

a customer can be either a Physical Person or a Company and that a Company has employees that are themselves physical persons. Company has also some persons who work for them as contractors who are physical persons but are not customers.

Could someone has any good idea and writes this model in yuml use cases http://yuml.me/ for example ?

Nobody seems to know UML Use Case so let's say even Class Diagram or even Java or C# Class Diagram or even database design :)

Problem I see in the model below is that Person is a Customer and so all employees would also be customers which is wrong:

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do, a use case? a sequence diagram? a class diagram?

Comment: As I said UML Use Case but if not Class Diagram

Comment: You misunderstand class diagrams. That class diagram does not specify that a specific employee must be a customer of the same company. The class diagram specifies possible relations between classes not instances. There may be some `Person` instances that are employees of a specific `Company`, there may be some `Person`s that are customers of that `Company`, and there may be some of that that are both employees and customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following class diagram fulfills your needs:

[image: class diagram]

You are actually working with two domains: the first domain is the hierarchy of the company: a company has employees and contractors which are persons; the second domain is the domain of customers, which can be companies and customers. So in this diagram you have a `Person` which can be a `Contractor`, an `Employee` or a `CustomerPerson`, which can also be a `Customer`, and you have a `CustomerCompany` which is both a `Customer` and a `Company`.

Note that I created `CustomerCompany` which inherits from `Company` instead of making `Company` inherit from `Customer` since I assume not all companies are customers.

I used inheritance for all relations, but if multiple inheritance is not wanted, this can be done using interface.

The [yuml](http://yuml.me) code for this diagram is:

```
[Company]++-0..*>[Employee]
[Company]++-0..*>[Contractor]
[Person]^-[Employee]
[Person]^-[Contractor]
[Customer]^-[CustomerCompany]
[Company]^-[CustomerCompany]
[Customer]^-[CustomerPerson]
[Person]^-[CustomerPerson]
```

Comment: Thanks, marked it as good answer. Will try further to implement it and see what problem I would encounter.

Answer (score 1):

> A Customer can be either a physical Person or a Company and that a Company has employees that are themselves physical Persons.

You cannot model this with UML use-case diagram as this is not a use-case. A use-case would sound like that a Compary can hire employees, a Person can order a product from the Company, and so on.

However you can model this with the following UML class diagram:
[image: Class diagram to model the problem]

**UPDATE:**

The class diagram above does not imply that an employee of a Company must also be a Customer of the same company. It just states that a Person may be a customer of some Company or an employee of the company, and permits both at the same time.

Consider the following object diagram that shows some instances of the above classes, and is perfectly legal in terms of the class diagram above:

[image: Class diagram with separate customers and employees]

Comment: Thanks will look at it. By the way Customer, Person and Company are roles in an UML Use Case

Comment: Problem I see in your model is that Person is a Customer and so all employees would also be customers which is wrong.

Comment: To be more clear: Company has also some persons who work for them as contractors who are physical persons but are not customers.

Comment: @user310291: The class diagram I've drawn allows this, see the update.

Comment: "a Person may be a customer of some Company": I don't understand how you can say "May" because inheritance means "IS A" ? And if customer was a class interface, the relation would mean MUST implement the interface customer ?